# EOF Error in Huffman Zip Program

Tags: java, io, huffman-code

I am creating a simple zip program that can take in any file and create a Huffman Tree out of it. I save the frequencies of each byte in a HashMap and then I create the Huffman Tree based off of the bytes and frequencies. I then use an ObjectOutputStream to write both the Huffman Tree node and an object that contains the original frequencies and the bitsequence that can decode the Huffman Tree. When running my test files, I am getting an EOF exception. I am closing my output streams, but I'm afraid I have a bug or two in my code that is causing this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("No files provided!");
        return;
    }
    if(args.length == 1 )
    {
        System.out.println("Missing at least one file!");
        return;
    }
    byte[] data = null;
    String pathname = args[0];
    String outputname = args[1];

    File initial = new File(pathname);
    File file = new File(outputname);

    if(!file.exists())
    {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create new file");
        }
    }

    if(!initial.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("This file does not exist");
        return;
    }

    if(file.canRead() || !initial.canRead())
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot read the file!");
        return;
    }

    if(!file.canWrite())
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot write to file!");
        return;
    }


    Path path1 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(args[0]);
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        //Byte data cannot be read
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    // map each byte value to its frequency count
    HashMap<Byte, Integer> values = new HashMap<Byte, Integer>();
    for (byte b : data) {
        if (values.containsKey(b)) {
            values.put(b, values.get(b) + 1); // add one to current count
        } else {
            values.put(b, 1);
        }
    }
    //Create HuffmanTree
    Node n = Node.makeHuffmanTree(values);

    //Initialize BitSequence
    BitSequence bs = new BitSequence();

    //Get final HashMap from HuffmanTreeNode
    HashMap<Byte, String> map = Node.buildPath(n, "", new HashMap<Byte, String>());

    //Iterate through original byte array, append BitSequence
    String s = "";
    for (byte a : data) {
        s += map.get(a);
        bs.appendBits(s);
    }

    //Create HuffmanSave
    HuffmanSave hs = new HuffmanSave(bs, values);

    //Create ObjectOutputStream and FileOutputStream
    try {

        //Write the BitSequence and the HuffmanSave to the file
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        oos.writeObject(n);
        oos.writeObject(hs);
        oos.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Could not write Objects to File
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    //Close the output streams

}
```

Here is my Node class that builds the Huffman Tree and builds and gets the path to each leaf node

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node parent;
    static byte bytes;
    int freq;

    public Node(byte newbyte, int newfreq) {
        bytes = newbyte;
        freq = newfreq;
    }

    public Node(int newfreq) {
        freq = newfreq;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node n) {
        if (freq < n.freq) {
            return -1;
        } else if (freq > n.freq) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static Node makeHuffmanTree(Map<Byte, Integer> map) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        for (Entry<Byte, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            Node n = new Node(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            queue.add(n);
        }

        Node root = null;
        while (queue.size() > 1) {
            Node first = queue.poll();
            Node second = queue.poll();
            Node combined = new Node(first.freq + second.freq);
            combined.right = first;
            combined.left = second;
            first.parent = combined;
            second.parent = combined;
            queue.add(combined);

            root = combined;
        }
        return root;
    }

    public static HashMap<Byte, String> buildPath(Node n, String s, HashMap<Byte, String> map) {
        if (n.left != null)
        {
            s += "0";
            return buildPath(n.left, s, map);
        }
        if (n.right != null){
            s += "1";
            return buildPath(n.right, s, map);
        }
        if (n.left == null && n.right == null) {
            map.put(bytes, s);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

The Stack trace is as follows:

java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2335)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at ZipTest.loadSaved(ZipTest.java:200)
    at ZipTest.testByteFileCorrectEncodingLength(ZipTest.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

ZipTest method that is getting the error:

```
private HuffmanSave loadSaved(String name) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(new File(name));
    ObjectInputStream in;
    in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    HuffmanSave result = (HuffmanSave) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    fileIn.close();
    return result;
  }
```

and method that calls the loadSaved()

```
 @Test
  public void testTextFileCorrectEncodingLength() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Zip.main(new String[] {"mary.txt", "mary.dmz"});

    HuffmanSave result = loadSaved("mary.dmz");
    assertEquals(227, result.getEncoding().length());
  }
```

Comment: *I am getting an EOF exception* **where ?**

Comment: Could you please add stacktrace of exception?

Comment: And also please add `ZipTest.loadSaved` method, and pointing 200th line in this method.

Comment: I think that bug in your test files. When you read saved files you have this exception.

Comment: @AlykoffGali I sent my test files to a friend, and he told me he could get the Zip and Unzip to pass my tests, so I'm afraid there is something wrong with my ObjectInputStream or ObjectOutputStream

Comment: You are trying to read an empty stream.